# Can't shut down the computer

Tags: 13.04, shutdown, log

When I shut down my computer, it doesn't shut down, only the screen "In progress" is showing, so that I have to push the power button.

How do I investigate where the problem is?

Comment: How are you shutting down?  Try this in terminal `sudo shutdown -h now`

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using?? is it a fresh installation or did it start sometime after? some extra info might help

Comment: Add some hardware info also please. And while you are shutting down press the down arrow key, to hide the logo and see the messages.

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden, 13.04. Previously everything was ok.

Comment: @falconer, I'll try to do that.

Comment: @Alex, Did you recently install anything new or did it just appear after an update?? by the by are you using an optimus graphical card (nvidia)?? There have been some reports with similar problems regarding computers with optimus cards and there is a solution for that

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden, installed something new.

Comment: Could you try to purge the newly installed program??

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden, no.

Comment: @Alex, Could you then perhaps try to kill the program before shutting down and see if that helps??

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden, I have many programs installed recently.

Comment: @Alex, Then I would really like you to press the down key when the splash screen pops up and check where it halts. That would help.

Answer (score 1):

Please [check this page](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/speed-up-ubuntu-shutdown-process/)
He gives some nice info that helped me with a problem similar.

1. gksudo gedit /etc/init/network-manager.conf
2. Under *stop on stopping bus*, add
3. kill timeout 1

He also advises to

1. sudo apt-get autoremove modemmanager

But that step wasn't necessary for me.

Of course this might be trick for production environments.
Use it only for personal computers and things like that

Comment: I would personally set the timeout a bit higher but ooh well

Comment: I don't have `stopping on bus`, I have only `stopping on dbus`. Are those the same?